# Why is SendMessage designed to behave different in a window's procedure than in worker threads?

Tags: windows, winapi

At first I would ask you to please don't misunderstand the question. I'm not asking how does SendMessage works, but why was it designed to work the way it does. Basically, I'm wondering why couldn't the call to a window procedure be made directly from a worker thread, the same way it is made from the window thread, instead of a message being pumped into the message queue?

In a very simple case in a worker thread I could just do:

```
WndProc(hWnd,MY_MESSAGE,wParam,lParam);
```

instead of:

```
SendMessage(hWnd,MY_MESSAGE,wParam,lParam);
```

and get the response immediately. Are there any drawbacks when you just call WndProc directly?

I can understand that things get more complicated, when you would like to send a message to a window that is owned by another process, but couldn't there exist a SendMessage-like function that works the same in a worker thread like in the window thread? Is there any reason behind that there doesn't exist any? Thank you in advance for any explanation.

Comment: It boils down to the fact that windows have affinity to the thread that created them. So this behaviour is part of what makes the system threadsafe.

Comment: There just isn't any point in writing code like this.  You instead refactor the window procedure and move the code inside the case: statement into a separate function.  And call that function.  The point of SendMessage() is that you don't know about the implementation details of the window.  In which case calling it from another thread is an excellent way to shoot your leg off.  There's always far too much code hanging off the message plumbing that is drastically thread-unsafe.  Like anti-malware, accessibility, windows hooks, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The writers of window procedures expect all of the calls to be made on one thread.  By using `SendMessage`, the message can be placed on a (thread-safe) queue.  A single thread can take the messages off the queue and pass them to the window procedure.

The drawback is that calling `WndProc` from another thread introduces race conditions.  Certain UI objects have thread affinity.  If that is not respected (e.g. by calling `WndProc` from another thread) then this can cause issues.  Device contexts are an example of this.  According to [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/10/10/479124.aspx)

> Window objects have thread affinity. The thread that creates a window is the one with which the window has an inseparable relationship. Informally, one says that the thread "owns" the window. Messages are dispatched to a window procedure only on the thread that owns it, and generally speaking, modifications to a window should be made only from the thread that owns it. Although the window manager permits any thread to access such things as window properties, styles, and other attributes such as the window procedure, and such accesses are thread safe from the window manager's point of view, load-modify-write sequences should typically be restricted to the owner thread. Otherwise you run into race conditions...

Comment: The windows GUI certainly is threadsafe. There rules relating to thread affinity that you need to follow. The entire Windows API is threadsafe. Again providing that you follow the threading rules.